# equivalence laws example proof

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Problem taken from [here](http://ballinger.disted.camosun.bc.ca/math126/Example%20of%20a%20Proof%20Using%20Logical%20Equivalences.pdf).

> Use Logical Equivalences to prove that $[(p \land \lnot(\lnot p \lor q)) \lor (p \land q)] \implies p$ is a tautology.

- implication law...
  $\lnot[(p \land \lnot(\lnot p \lor q)) \lor (p \land q)] \lor p $
- demorgans $[\lnot(p \land \lnot(\lnot p \lor q)) \land \lnot(p \land q)] \lor p$
- demorgans $[\lnot(p \land \lnot(\lnot p \lor q)) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)] \lor p$
- demorgans $[(\lnot p \lor (\lnot p \lor q)) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)] \lor p$
- distribution... $[(\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)] \lor p$
- distribution... $[(\lnot p \lor (q \land \lnot q)] \lor p$
- negation... $[\lnot p \lor F] \lor p$
- associativity $(p \lor \lnot p) \lor f$
- domination $T \lor F$
- $T$

does this make sense? i just want to make sure there are multiple ways to go about it. obviously implication would be better saved till the end but on an exam etc. just want to make sure I know multiple ways to get there.

Comment: If $p$ is true, then the implication is true since it has a true conclusion; and if $p$ is false, then both clauses of the antecedent will be false, so the implication will again be true. So it is a tautology. Why bother with all those steps? In any case, the truth table has only four rows, and so it is easier to just compute the truth table.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{blue}{\checkmark \mathrm A{-}}$

Your steps are correct, although some of their justifications don't match them.

- The first 'distribution' is actually 'association and idempotence'.
- The 'associativity' should be 'association and commutation'.

Other than that, spot on.